# Как скрыть кнопку Facebook Login Button на Activity, в момент когда авторизация одобрена и следует переход на другое Activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebooksdk

Для входа в приложение я использую Facebook SDK и кнопку для входа. После нажатие на которую появляется Activity авторизации (из Facebook SDK) где вводятся данные пользователя и стартует другая Activity (приложения). Суть проблемы заключается в том, что при переходе на другое Activity, после одобрения авторизации через Facebook, на 1-2 секунды видна кнопка из Facebook SDK на которой надпись уже изменилась на "Выход из Facebook". Как сделать что бы при удачном логировании Activity с кнопкой уже не отображалась?

Код Button

```
loginFacebookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginFacebookButton);
    loginFacebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("user_friends"));

        }
    });
```

Код FacebookCallback

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        }
    };
```

Код onActivityResult

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```